# Laravel 5.6 storing API's session token server side

Tags: laravel, api

I have a laravel app that consumes an API.
Users can authenticate sending the email and password to the API which then verifies them with the database and sends back a randomly generated token which can be used to authenticate further calls with the API.
The laravel app uses `CURL` to call the API.

Now, I know that I can use laravel's `session()` to store the token, which I can further use into the API calls.
However, I don't feel like this is the best practice or the best way to do this in laravel.

Which brings me to my question, is this the best way to store API tokens in laravel?(server side)
Should I implement this by extending laravel's `Auth` with a custom guard?(kinda feels like to much overhead for a simple token storing concept).

What are the best practices in this cases?
Thank you.

Comment: So you have an APP with GUI (where login happens), that does some magic with 3rd party API?

Comment: @Kyslik exactly, there's a GUI which has a login page where users send their email and password to the API

Comment: Wait a second, so you have an app that acts as relay / bridge for the API login process? Do you own the API or its 3rd party?

Comment: @Kyslik exactly

Comment: have you looked at laravel Passport? that probably works. but if it doesn't, YES, you have to extend Auth and define a new guard. I had the same problem lately and after a lot of headache and trying different ways, I had to do that

Comment: @FatemehMajd hmm, I know Passport, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I think I'll have to settle with a custom `Auth` guard.